# How would I dynamically clone a site and apply custom css to it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, django

So my school has a "portal"; a site with heaps of resources for the students and teachers. Only downside is that it is really, really badly designed and runs on HTML4. I have some decent web design skills and I want to try and improve it. I have asked if I could directly edit it and I was very quickly shut down. So how would I go about cloning the site while applying custom CSS?
While doing an iframe seems like a great idea to start with, it is quickly stopped by CORS. You can't apply custom CSS to an iframe with an origin of a different domain.
I could just download the site's source code and write custom CSS for that, but that way it won't update when new content is updated.
I am happy to play around with django/flask if needed since I have a lot of experience with python and if it works, I can create a downloadable app using react or something.
Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: clone the whole site? Why not just start with a page - I'm a php guy and it's 1 line of code to `$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');`, then you can use a dom parser to do anything from shoehorn in your own css definitions to picking apart and restructuring the content.

Comment: This is not a trivial task. You could implement a reverse proxy, or just develop a browser extension or a userscript that "modernizes" the web site in question.

Comment: @Kinglish You reckon PHP is the way to go? And I could probably apply the same process to every page by webscraping the URLs.
But could you point me to some resources regarding cloning pages with PHP?

Comment: Wouldnt a custom extension for your browser or even an existing extension be better? From what i can see here, you just want to inject some css to a specific url pattern. [Google search: browser extension css injector](https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+extension+css+injector)

Answer (score 0):

1. Just go to the website you want to clone
2. Right click
3. Inspect element
4. Copy the whole html code
5. Paste it to you code editor
6. Add a tag a `<style>`
7. Enter Css to customize it with respect to the tags of the html code
8. You are done!!!
   Happy coding :)

Comment: I appreciate the attempt but the issue with that is that it won't update. Since this is a site full of resources and gets updated a lot, that would only be an effective method for about a week.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to clone someone else's terribly built website, I would use PHP and DOM parsing.

https://codingreflections.com/php-parse-html/

In a perfect world, their code will follow some kind of pattern and, using the DOM parser, you'd be able to pick out their navigation and internal href links, and rewrite them to point to your site like `http://terriblewebsite.com/aboutus.phtml => http://imborrowingyourwebsite.com?page=http://terriblewebsite.com/aboutus.phtml`.

I would write all my css in a single file, remove their `<link` tags and insert my own css file links -- but use their classes as much as possible.

Your index.php file would basically be (this is a rough sketch)

```
<?php
$url = "http://terriblewebsite.com";
if ($_GET['url']) $url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$dom = new DomDocument();
@ $dom->loadHTML($url);

// change nav
$nav = $dom->getElementById('navbar'); //DOMElement
$nav_links = $nav->getElementsByTagName('a'); //DOMNodeList
foreach($nav_links as $item) {
 $item->setAttribute('href', 'http://imborrowingyourwebsite.com?page='.$item->getAttribute('href'));
}

// ... other transformations...
// finally

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```